# How to retrive specific row from html table equal of something by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table dynamically  generated by php. In this table have information for different semester (such as : first, second, third etc). Now i want to show specific semester information if user click a link from same table without a query. I am newbie in this forum and its my first question. sorry for poor english. !

My code

```
<table id="course_offering" class="table table-striped table-hover custab ">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Course Code</th>
        <th>Course title</th>
        <th>Credit Hours</th>
        <th>Contact Hours</th>
        <th>Pre Requisite</th>
        <th>Course Type</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Semester</th>
        <th>Offering Year</th>
        <th>Offering Session</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>     

<tr>
<td>EEE 2505</td>
<td>Electrical </td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td></td>
<td>Theory</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2014</td>
<td> Spring </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>EEE 2505</td>
<td>Electrical </td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td></td>
<td>Theory</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>2015</td>
<td> Spring </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>EEE 2505</td>
<td>Electrical </td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td></td>
<td>Theory</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>2014</td>
<td> Spring </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>EEE 2505</td>
<td>Electrical </td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td></td>
<td>Theory</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>2014</td>
<td> Spring </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>EEE 2505</td>
<td>Electrical </td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td></td>
<td>Theory</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>2014</td>
<td> Spring </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>EEE 2505</td>
<td>Electrical </td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td></td>
<td>Theory</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>2014</td>
<td> Spring </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>EEE 2505</td>
<td>Electrical </td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td></td>
<td>Theory</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>2014</td>
<td> Spring </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: We need to see your code to be able to help you.

Comment: you want to retrieve row depending on the text contents of the row? can you give an example?

Comment: i tried to add a screenshot but for lake of reputation i failed . i am uploading code soon.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/4z143lvz7/ please visit this link i upload a screenshot

Comment: You say click link on table but I see no links in the table. Do you mean click on a row?

Comment: How do you want to show the new information? In a new table? In a modal window (popup) ?

Comment: @CodeToad Modal window will be best.

Comment: all all rows clickable? what information do you need from the row? the course code?

Answer (score 0):

here is a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/K7PjR/1/

```
function getRowsByText(text) {
var resultRows = $();

$('tr').each(function () {
    var row = $(this);
    var rowText = row.text().trim();
    if (rowText === text) {
      resultRows = resultRows.add(row); //return the row
    }
   });
          return resultRows;
   }
   getRowsByText('apple').css('color', 'red');

   getRowsByText('orange').css('color', 'orange');
```

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>apple</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>orange</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>bannana</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: How exactly does this answer the question? The OP wants an action to happen when a row is clicked. He/She mentioned nothing about color changes...

Comment: i want to select all table row where semester(td) equal of something and generate a full table. i am newbie. please elaborate little more..

Comment: exactly i want an  action to happen when a link in sidebar is clicked. when i clicked First Semester it will show me the row where contain semester equal of first. that it . i can do it by php but if will looks hazard. i want to keep it simple by jquery of something. is there any way to query like php in jquery to retrieve data form table.

Comment: @War10ck stackoverflow is meant as a place where programmers help other programmers, not where programmers write code for non-programmers for free. if he wants a solid answer, he should try the problem and write what he has when asking a question, not just assuming that someone will write the code for him.

@ Mehedi CodeToad has shown you how to grab certain elements, now try something yourself. if you update your code we can help you. If you sit by idly then expect others to do the same.

Comment: the question see ms to have been edited since I read it. before it said to find row by value, which I assume meant text. by providing a working example, I hope to show the asker a simple example of one approach tot he problem. the colors are not what he asked for, they are just a way to demonstrate a use of the function

Comment: @Cole I understand that. This doesn't even remotely qualify as an answer. It answers no part of the OP's question. I do agree, that the OP should show what he/she has tried. However, if the OP is being unclear, you should ask for clarification rather than posting an answer that has no relevance.

Comment: i updated my code snippet. i thought my question is so simple no need to show code, because i want to know the way how to do this. i am not facing a problem of syntax. And i know that stackoverflow is meant as a place where programmers help other programmers and i am not willing that other programmer write code for me. sorry COLE. now i upload my code example if you could help me out.

Comment: if you look at my comment, i asked for clarification. as for "remotely answering his question," look at the question title: "How to retrive specific row from html table equal of something by jquery"